# iOS back button behaviour : double back

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, navigationcontroller

I have 3 view controllers :
A ->segue1-> B ->segue2-> C

When the user is on "C" and press the "back" button, I would like to go directly to A instead of B.
How can I do that with swift ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigation controller you can use **popToRootViewControllerAnimated(_:)**.

In case you have presented both controllers modally you can call **dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)** in your A controller.

Create your own back button :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
```

And pop to root controller :

```
-(void)tapped:(UIButton*)sender {
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated(NO)];
}
```

Comment: override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?){ self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {}); } displays B from C but not A.

Comment: You dont't need willMoveToParentViewController. This is used for adding child controller inside another controller. Just call popToRootViewController if you are using push segue(navigation contorller) or dismissViewController in your A controller object.

Comment: I need to override the back button in the C screen. Instead of C->B, I want C->A

Comment: Use popToRootViewControllerAnimated in your back button action.

Comment: I don't have a back button in my storyboard. The back button is  created automatically by the navigation controller. popToRootViewControllerAnimated displays a black screen :(